# Вывод записей с помощью get_queried_object

Tags: php, wordpress

Если в шаблоне taxonomy.php прописать так:

```
$current_term_obj = get_queried_object();
echo '<pre>';
var_export($current_term_obj);
echo '</pre>';
```

то в возвращаемом результате поле 'count' показывает количество имеющихся записей в данной категории. В данном случае количество показывает верное, т.е. поле count содержит количество записей в данной категории.
Но если создать такой код на этой же странице:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $current_term_obj->slug,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $current_term_obj->term_id
        )
    )
);
$_post = get_posts($args);

echo '<pre>';
var_export($_post);
echo '</pre>';
```

то $_post не содержит найденные записи, count($_post) = 0
Подскажите, как правильно достать записи из бд на основе get_queried_object() ?
Таксономии произвольные

Answer (score 0):

Но на странице таксономии по умолчанию global $wp_query - несет в себе выборку постов текущей таксономии. Все ровно кастомной или стандартной.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.
            the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentysixteen' ),
                'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentysixteen' ),
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
            ) );

        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
```

Это должно работать!